# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Linking the color of one mesh to a second mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23183/linking-the-color-of-one-mesh-to-a-second-mesh)

**Net Score: 19** (Excellent: 19, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Error extruding loop selection along individual face normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/error-extruding-loop-selection-along-individual-face-normals)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can't find the palette to alter new objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/cant-find-the-palette-to-alter-new-objects)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Mesh displayed as dots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23336/mesh-displayed-as-dots)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I control where smoke and fire are emitted from?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/fire-smoke-appearing-from-corner)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Animate object on arc trajectory](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21400/animate-object-on-arc-trajectory)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Importing time-dependent mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23349/importing-time-dependent-mesh)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Moving animations between computers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/moving-animations-between-computers)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Alpha image or model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22857/alpha-image-or-model)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Add a ''glossy'' material for Blender render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23234/add-a-glossy-material-for-blender-render)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 2)

---